# Need to find a string in group, then to find all groups where single group (containing a string) belongs to

Tags: perl

I have text.csv file which contains IP addresses and groups with ip addresses. I can easily find into which single group IP 10.1.1.1 belongs to. Problem is that i would need to find all groups where group (with found IP) also belongs to. Let suppose there might be many groups.

I have tried below code to find a group into which IP belongs to but i don't know how to find other groups in loop. Let see a file text.csv:

```
Group name,Group members
------------------------
Group1    ,Group2
Group2    ,Group3
Group3    ,10.1.1.1
Group4    ,10.1.1.1 
Group5    ,Group2
```

My code so far:

```
my $ip = "10.1.1.1";         

$csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ',' });
open(DATA, "< :encoding(iso-8859-7)", "text.csv") or die "Could not open $!\n";               

 while (<DATA>) {    
  if ($csv->parse($_)) {

   @column_all           = $csv->fields();
   $column_name          = $column_all[0];
   $column_group_member  = $column_all[1];


   if ($column_group_member =~ /$ip/) {
    $object = $column_name;
    print $column_name;     
   }


   if ($column_group_member =~ /$objectH/) {
    print $column_name;
   }


  }
 }
```

This will print only Group3 because it has IP 10.1.1.1

Result should be:
Group3 (because it contains IP 10.1.1.1)
Group2 (because it contains Group3)
Group1 (because it contains Group2)

Answer (score 3):

We want to know to which groups each member belongs, so we'll create a Hash of Arrays (HoA) keyed by member that contains all the groups to which the member (directly) belongs.

`push @{ $hash{$key} }, $value;` is a common way to build an HoA.

Once this HoA is built, we'll determine the groups to which the IP address belongs, then we'll determine the groups to which each of those groups belong, and so forth.

In case the IP belongs two two groups that both belong the same group (directly or otherwise), we'll need to filter out the groups we've previously seen.

`my %seen; my @unique = grep !$seen{$_}++, @values;` is a common way to filter out duplicates.

Solution:

```
use strict;                            # ALWAYS use this.
use warnings;                          # ALWAYS use this.
use feature qw( say );

use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );  # Optional. Can use sort or leave unsorted instead.
use Text::CSV_XS       qw( );          # Faster than Text::CSV, but otherwise identical.

my $ip  = "10.1.1.1";
my $qfn = "text.csv";

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   auto_diag => 2,                     # Die on errors.
   binary    => 1,                     # Should always have this.
});

# "DATA" already exists, and you shouldn't be using global vars.
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(iso-8859-7)", $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my %belongs_to;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {    # Proper way to use $csv
   my ($member, $group) = @$row;

   # Add $group to the array referenced by $belongs_to{$member}.
   # The array is autovivified as if we had used « $belongs_to{$member} //= []; ».
   push @{ $belongs_to{$member} }, $group;
}

# Recursively determine to which groups $ip belongs.
my %groups;
my @groups;
my @todo = $ip;
while (@todo) {
   my $member = shift(@todo);

   # Add every group we haven't encountered yet to @groups and @todo.
   my @new_groups = grep !$groups{$_}++, @{ $belongs_to{$member} };
   push @groups, @new_groups;
   push @todo,   @new_groups;
}

@groups = natsort @groups;  # Make the results more presentable.

say for @groups;
```

(There are ways of optimizing the last part, but the gains are minimal, and utmost clarity is more important here.)